# xcode: selecting view by parameter

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, properties

How can I select the UIView by using a parameter?

**Example:**

I have two UIViews. The first one contains some UILabels and UIButtons. The second one contains the same stuff, but in addition an Image.

The UIViewController has a property imageExists. Depending on the value of this property, the UIView should be selected. How is this done?

Comment: I didn't understand! I think you don't need two views. Instead, you should control the visibility of your addition image.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that this is possible. I'll try this.